# Error handling in ionic2/ Angular2

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic2, laravel-5.4

Trying to integrate APIs built in Laravel 5.4 with ionic 2 and struggling handle the error

What I want to do:

- Authenticate the login using Laravel Password service ( OAuth2 ).
- Once authenticated, it would return the access token.
- Access Token is passed in the header in a GET API call to receive the
  user details.

I am able to #1 and #2 but got stuck at #3.

Here is my code of login.ts

```
public login() {
        this.showLoading();
        this.auth.login(this.loginCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
            if (allowed) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.loading.dismiss();
                    this.nav.setRoot(HelloIonicPage)
                });
            } else {
                this.showError("Access Denied");
            }
        },
        error => {
            this.showError(error);
        });
    }
```

auth is a service provider, that has login method.

```
//Function to get access token

public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
        return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            var link = 'http://localhost/XXX/public/oauth/token';
            var vars =  {
                password: "XXX",
                username: "XXXXXX",
                grant_type: 'password',
                client_id: "XXXXX",
                client_secret: 'XXXXXX',
                scope: ''
            }

            this.http.post(link, vars)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => { let user = this.getUserFromAccessToken(data);
                    console.log(user);
                    observer.next(user);
                },
                err => { observer.error(err.json()); }
                () => {
                    console.log('Completed..');
                }
            );


        });
    }
}


//Function to get user from the accessToken

private getUserFromAccessToken(oAuthData) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oAuthData.access_token });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let link = 'http://localhost/XXXX/public/api/v1/user';

    return this.http.get(link, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => this.currentUser = data.user,
        err => this.error = err
    );
}
```

`currentUser` and `error` are defined as properties of the AuthService class.

How should I ensure that an error is thrown either in case the access token is not returned or user is not returned from the access token.

Comment: I think you have already done everything right. I think your error is also present at appropriate positions. Now, where exactly you are facing problem? Like what error you need to throw when?

Comment: In getUserFromAccessToken method, if an invalid/ expired token is passed or the user that corresponds to the passed access token does not have a valid subscription, server throws an error/ exception. However, this method does not return any error to the method it is called from.

Comment: Can you confirm that the desired error thrown by server is indeed present at the method `getUserFromAccessToken(oAuthData)`. This will ensure there is no issue on Server side and it is returning correct error. You can do a `console.log("Data",data)` and `console.log("Error",error)` in the method where you are setting the values for `currentUser` and `error`.

Comment: Also, just realized, I think `let user = this.getUserFromAccessToken(data)` this part needs to be handled correctly. If you can first confirm the previous comment I will put an answer. Need that info to be precise.